# TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\services\Fields::getGroupById() must be of the type integer, null given

Tags: craft3, error-message

When I go to control panel > Settings > Fields, I get a page that throws `TypeError: Argument 1 passed to craft\services\Fields::getGroupById() must be of the type integer, null given`

This is identical to the issue described here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/3561

Any ideas as to what might be causing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to an issue with your project-config being out of sync somehow. You could try the new `./craft project-config/rebuild` console command [that's just been added to Craft](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/develop/CHANGELOG-v3.md#3120---2019-03-27) and see if that gets you back on track.